# How to access Redis as a k8s service with NestJS TypeORM's cache server option?

Tags: kubernetes, redis, nestjs, typeorm

I'd like to deploy my k8s with NestJS backend server and redis.

In order to remove `user service` from the core service of `NestJS`, I would like to run `user service` as a service of k8s, and use the cache server of user db referenced by the `user service` as a service in k8s.

To do that, I set up the user service's database config module like this.

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { TypeOrmModule, TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import { SnakeNamingStrategy } from 'typeorm-naming-strategies'

let DATABASE_NAME = 'test'
if (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  DATABASE_NAME = `${DATABASE_NAME}_${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
}

const DB_HOST: string = process.env.DB_HOST ?? 'localhost'
const DB_USERNAME: string = process.env.DB_USERNAME ?? 'user'
const DB_PASSWORD: string = process.env.DB_PASSWORD ?? 'password'
const REDIS_HOST: string = process.env.REDIS_HOST ?? 'localhost'

const databaseConfig: TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions = {
  useFactory: (): TypeOrmModuleOptions => ({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: DB_HOST,
    port: 3306,
    username: DB_USERNAME,
    password: DB_PASSWORD,
    database: DATABASE_NAME,
    autoLoadEntities: true,
    synchronize: true,
    namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
    logging: false,
    cache: {
      type: 'redis',
      options: {
        host: REDIS_HOST,
        port: 6379,
      },
    },
    timezone: '+09:00',
  }),
}
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      ...databaseConfig,
    }),
  ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

And, to implement k8s I used a `helm`.

Helm's template folders are as follows.

```bash
- configmap
- deployment
- pod
- service
```

And, under those folders are as follows.

```yaml
// configmap/redis.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: redis-config
data:
  redis-config: |
    maxmemory 20mb
    maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

```yaml
// deployment/user_service.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-service
  labels:
    app: user-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-service
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: {{ .Values.user_service.image }}:{{ .Values.user_service_version }}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: user-service
        ports:
        - containerPort: 50051
          protocol: TCP
        env:
        - name: COGNITO_CLIENT_ID
          value: "some value"
        - name: COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID
          value: "some value"
        - name: DB_HOST
          value: "some value"
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          value: "some value"
        - name: DB_USERNAME
          value: "some value"
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: "test"
        - name: REDIS_HOST
          value: "10.100.77.0"
```

```yaml
// pod/redis.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
      app: redis
spec:
  containers:
  - name: redis
    image: redis:latest
    command:
      - redis-server
      - "/redis-master/redis.conf"
    env:
    - name: MASTER
      value: "true"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 6379
      name: redis
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /redis-master-data
      name: data
    - mountPath: /redis-master
      name: config
  volumes:
    - name: data
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: config
      configMap:
        name: redis-config
        items:
        - key: redis-config
          path: redis.conf
```

```yaml
// service/user_service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: user-service
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.100.88.0
  selector:
    app: user-service
  ports:
   -  protocol: TCP
      port: 50051
      targetPort: 50051
```

```yaml
// service/redis.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.100.77.0
  selector:
    app: redis
  ports:
  - name: redis
    protocol: TCP
    port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
```

With above yaml files, I install helm chart named test.

After installing, the result of `kubectl get svc,po,deploy,configmap` is like this.

```bash
NAME                              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
service/kubernetes                ClusterIP   10.100.0.1    <none>        443/TCP     4d4h
service/user-service   ClusterIP   10.100.88.0   <none>        50051/TCP   6s
service/redis                     ClusterIP   10.100.77.0   <none>        6379/TCP    6s

NAME                                           READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
pod/user-service-78548d4d8f-psbr2   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          6s
pod/redis                                      0/1     ContainerCreating   0          6s

NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/user-service   0/1     1            0           6s

NAME                         DATA   AGE
configmap/kube-root-ca.crt   1      4d4h
configmap/redis-config       1      6s
```

But, when I checked the user-service's deploy logs, these error was occurred.

```bash
[Nest] 1  - 02/07/2023, 7:15:32 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
```

I also checked through the console log that the `REDIS_HOST` environment variable is `10.100.77.0` in the database config of `user-service`, but an error was appearing while referring to the local host as above.

Is there any error in the part I set?

Answer (score 0):

you can use service for connect to Redis.  for this use `redis.redis` as `REDIS_HOST` in your application.

Comment: I followed your answer, but it did not work... ;)